# cabal sdist: tests inappropriate type

Tags: haskell, cabal

I just completed my first executable + library + tests in Haskell.
Unfortunately I can't create the tar-ball with the `cabal sdist` command.

`cabal install --enable-tests && cabal build && cabal test` are working without problems

`cabal check` returns only the warning for `-O2`

```
>> cabal sdist --verbose
creating dist/src
creating dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0
Distribution quality warnings:
'ghc-options: -O2' is rarely needed. Check that it is giving a real benefit
and not just imposing longer compile times on your users.
Building source dist for UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing library UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'UTFTConverter' for UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing test suite 'library-tests:' for UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0...
creating dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/src
creating dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/src/Format
creating dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/tests
creating dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0
Installing src/Format.hs to
dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/src/Format.hs
Installing src/Format/C.hs to
dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/src/Format/C.hs
Installing src/Format/Converter.hs to
dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/src/Format/Converter.hs
Installing src/Format/Raw.hs to
dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/src/Format/Raw.hs
Installing src/Format/RGB565.hs to
dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/src/Format/RGB565.hs
Installing src/Main.hs to
dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/src/Main.hs
Installing tests/Tests.hs to
dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/tests/Tests.hs
Installing LICENSE to dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/LICENSE
Installing Setup.lhs to dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/Setup.lhs
Installing ./UTFTConverter.cabal to
dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/./UTFTConverter.cabal
creating dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0
Installing tests to dist/src/sdist.-15440/UTFTConverter-0.1.0.0/tests
cabal: tests: inappropriate type
```

My cabal version is

```
>> cabal -V
cabal-install version 1.18.1.0
using version 1.18.1.3 of the Cabal library
```

My GHC version is

```
>> ghc -V
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3
```

Here is the github page to the project, maybe somebody can reproduce this error. [>> Link <<](http://github.com/cirquit/UTFTConverter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `tests` from your `extra-source-files` section. You can't put directories in that section.